# What is the easy way to validate scheduling data in python

Tags: python, json

I have a *JSON* object that contains the scheduling of a single day.

```
{
    "timings":{
        "id":43,
        "partition":7,
        "day_name":"Tuesday",
        "full_day":false,
        "close_day":false,
        "start_time":"2022-12-20 00:00:00",
        "close_time":"2022-12-20 23:00:00"
    },
    "pricings":[
        {
            "partition":7,
            "day_name":"Tuesday",
            "peak_hours":true,
            "start_time":"2022-12-20 17:00:00",
            "close_time":"2022-12-20 23:00:00",
            "price":"1300"
        },
        {
            "partition":7,
            "day_name":"Tuesday",
            "peak_hours":true,
            "start_time":"2022-12-20 00:00:00",
            "close_time":"2022-12-20 04:00:00",
            "price":"1300"
        },
        {
            "id":54,
            "partition":7,
            "day_name":"Tuesday",
            "peak_hours":false,
            "start_time":"2022-12-20 04:00:00",
            "close_time":"2022-12-20 17:00:00",
            "price":2000
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see the first key is `timings`. Which contains the detail of the shop when it will open and when it'll close.

Then we move on to the second key which is `pricings`. It's a list of objects that contains that is it a peak hour or `off_peak_hours` or when they start and when they end.

How can we validate all timing values such as start times and close times of each entry?
they should not overlap each other and all time should be within shop *opening* and *closing* `timings`?

e.g with valid data:
the shop opens at **1 A.M.**
shop closes at **11 A.M.**

Now we have a list of hours:
first peak hours start at **1 A.M.** to **4 A.M.**
second `off_hours` starts from **4 A.M.** to **7 A.M.**
third `peak_hours` again starts at **7 A.M.** and to **11 A.M.**

e.g. invalid data:

The first peak hours start at **1 A.M.** to **5 A.M.**
second `off_hours` starts from **4 A.M.** to **7 A.M.**
third `peak_hours` again starts at **7 A.M.** and to **11 A.M.**

As you can see in the first line peak hour start from **1 A.M.** to **5 A.M.**
Second off hours start at **4 A.M.** to **7 A.M.**.

Here the problem comes that **`4` A.M.** to **`5` A.M.** overlapping that single hour is coming into a peak hour as well as an `off-peak` hour so that input is not valid.

Another case:

```
{
    "timings":{
        "id":43,
        "partition":7,
        "day_name":"Tuesday",
        "full_day":false,
        "close_day":false,
        "start_time":"2022-12-20 00:00:00",
        "close_time":"2022-12-20 22:00:00"
    },
    "pricings":[
        {
            "partition":7,
            "day_name":"Tuesday",
            "peak_hours":true,
            "start_time":"2022-12-20 17:00:00",
            "close_time":"2022-12-20 23:00:00",
            "price":"1300"
        },
        {
            "partition":7,
            "day_name":"Tuesday",
            "peak_hours":true,
            "start_time":"2022-12-20 00:00:00",
            "close_time":"2022-12-20 04:00:00",
            "price":"1300"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see in the `timings` my shop opens from **`00:00`** to **`22:00`**
in the `pricings` list, I have put the start time from **`17:00`** to **`23:00`**

It returns valid even though you can see **`22:00`** to **`23:00`** shop is not even on.

And it is handled by following code :

```py
for time in closeTime:
        if time > close :
            print("Not Valid")

    for time in startTime:
        if time < start:
            print("Not Valid")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming objects in the `pricings` list are entered in chronological order (start at 00:00:00, end at 23:59:59) then we can jsut check to mak sure the diffrence between the `i close_time` and `i+1 start_time` is 0. If it is any other number then there must be overlap.

This can be accomplished using `datetime`

```
import datetime

validFlag = True
for i in range(len(obj["pricings"])-1):
    currentClose = datetime.datetime.strptime(obj["pricings"][i]["close_time"],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    nextStart = datetime.datetime.strptime(obj["pricings"][i+1]["start_time"],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    if currentClose-nextStart==datetime.timedelta(0):
        pass
    else:
        validFlag = False

if validFlag:
    print("Valid")
else:
    print("Not Valid")
```

Here we take the strings that indicate the time, change them to date times, find the difference between them. If the difference is anything but 0, we check a flag that indicates that it is not a valid entry.

This works according to your wishes given that the entries are in chronological order. In your example however they are not. So we will go over an example for this as well. The only idffrence in this second example is the use of list.sort() to sort the times

```
startTime = []
    closeTime = []
    for i in range(len(obj["pricings"])):
        startTime.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(obj["pricings"][i]["start_time"],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        closeTime.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(obj["pricings"][i]["close_time"],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    startTime.sort()
    closeTime.sort()
    validFlag = True
    for i in range(len(startTime)-1):
        if closeTime[i]-startTime[i+1]==datetime.timedelta(0):
            pass
        else:
            validFlag = False

    if validFlag:
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Not Valid")
```

Comment: i have tested it with a new case that is invalid but it returns valid. i have put that in question

Comment: And yeah your code worked with most of the cases. Really appreciated brother. I'm marking this as an answer. but please review that new case on which this code isn't working Thank You.

Comment: I have also handled that case by adding the code that i'm mentioning in my question. Thank You.